# Jmeter Response Assertion Samples Not Failing

Tags: jmeter, assertions

I want to stop a thread based on the response assertion, but even though the response assertions are triggering, they are not failing the sample:

[image: JMeter Response Assertion Not Failing 1]
As you can see, the first 2 are not failing the sample, but the 3rd one('This page is no longer available'), is failing correctly.

The first 2 assertions are directly on the samples, which are nested under parent controllers, whereas the 3rd assertion is against multiple samples on the level above the bottom simple controller:

[image: JMeter Response Assertion Not Failing 1]

Note. If I move either of the first two assertions to the same level as the third assertion, then they correctly fail the sample.  But I don't want that as they are specific to their http requests.

Example of Response Assertion not failing sample at sample level, but working at level above:
[image: JMeter Response Assertion Not Failing 3]

Comment: I tried your scenario (global assertion + under sampler) and it's working as expected in JMeter 3.1. Can you provide details on "Missing Enroll Request ID" assertion (or another similar one)? also which version of JMeter, and whether you see anything in jmeter log

Comment: Thanks Kiril. My structure is: Loop Controller-> Transaction Controller-> Simple Controller.  My version is 3.0. I have added a screenshot of the response assertion above

Comment: Nothing in JMeter log and I've since upgraded to 3.2, where I see the same issue.

Comment: I tried that exact condition, and sampler is still reliably failing as it should. So I wonder if you are altering the status of the sampler in one of the post-processors you have. Maybe try to disable ALL other post-processors ("Get enrolement...", "Stop Thread if missing..." etc), and see if assertion still fails.